# Why is Curie trying to sell me chems?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing Fallout 4 after downloading the Far Harbour dlc, and my character will randomly say, "I'm looking for some chems." The camera will then rotate to Curie who is my current companion and bring up the screen to buy/sell. She had over 700 caps and a variety of chems to purchase. However, none of these things are in her inventory when we trade.

This won't stop happening even if I try buying chems from her or buy everything in her stock. It does it without any prompting from me and at completely random times even during combat. Have any of you experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

From the OP, originally posted as a comment:

> It finally stopped after I dismissed [Curie] and acquired her again. Still not really sure what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your character is not addict to Chems ? I would find logical that Curie automatically sells you chems if you need some, since she's supposed to be a nurse. Try changing companion or cure your chems addictions.

Answer (score -1):

This is normal, because it will always prompt that specific dialogue when Curie is your active companion.

It will go away once you have reached maximum affinity with her, or just choose another active companion, or go solo!

Hope that helps

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I don't recall this every happening any of the times I've had Curie with me, and I find no mention of it on [her Nukapedia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Curie).